# Merge 2 tables in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I would like to merge 2 tables, `Table3` and `Table5` in Power BI.

`Table3` is imported and `Table5` was manually built in Power BI, as shown below:

[image]

I tried to use "Merge Query" feature in Power BI Desktop, with left join on `Table3.Column1` and `Table5.Name`. I would expect to see the `Table5` as highlighted in red, but instead there is only one option of `Table3`. How could I merge these 2 tables?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enter the values in Power Query by using Enter Data command, To see where to find it , check the picture.

[image: Enter Data Command]

Then create your table by manually entering values:

[image: Create Your Table]

Then You can see the Table5 in Merge Dialog Box, see picture

[image: Merge]

Then: Combine (Merge) Tables

[image: Combine]

The result It returns:

[image: ResultSet]

Answer (score 1):

Table 5 is a calculated table and so cannot be merged in PQ. It has been derived from your model after PQ loads it. Create your table in PQ if you want to be able to merge it.